# how to handle space in user name as argument in command

Tags: cmd

I have a command:

```
C:\Users\superuser> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "c:\whrpr\Management\dcomperm.exe" 
                               -al {1FBEBA42-492E-11D4-9FE8-005004130589} 
                               set "Anonymous Logon" permit
```

Running this command, I get this error:

> 'c:\whrpr\Management\dcomperm.exe" -al {1FBEBA42-492E-11D4-9FE8-005004130589} set "Anonymous' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

And when I changed "Anonymous Logon" to Everyone, the command runs successfully.

How do I run this for `"Anonymous Logon"`?

Comment: Why are you running `cmd.exe` rather than just running `dcomperm.exe` **directly**?

Comment: actually this command runs automatically while build will be installed on client machine and cmd.exe used to run this command and dcomperm.exe help to set user permission. and this command runs successfully for "Everyone" user. 
so i need to run this completely at a time throw programming.

Comment: Your application - is it a Winforms app? Web app?

Comment: Web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to run `dcomperm.exe` directly, not via `cmd.exe`.

```
"c:\whrpr\Management\dcomperm.exe" -al {1FBEBA42-492E-11D4-9FE8-005004130589} set "Anonymous Logon" permit
```